# Does anyone knows how to use Mobile App Events?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush-android

We have integrated the Mobile Push SDK into our mobile application, and we can confirm that the mobile events are being sent correctly. We have thoroughly reviewed our implementation and confirmed that the events are being sent with the appropriate event parameters and are reaching Marketing Cloud successfully.

However, when we analyze the Journey Builder, we are unable to observe any corresponding entries or actions triggered by these mobile events. This behavior is concerning as it prevents us from effectively utilizing Journey Builder's capabilities to engage our mobile users with personalized experiences.

Has anyone faced the same issue ? We have contacted MC support but they are slow at providing a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The most common issue is related to how you created your events in the UI with: All, Some, or None.

The event is configured in the Marketing Cloud to accept the event's attributes, right?

So, if all is chosen, then all attributes defined in the server-side schema must be present when the SDK emits the event.

If some is chosen, then at least 1 of the attributes must be present when ...

If none is chosen, then the event must be emitted without any attributes.

Here's the gotcha: you many not include attributes the server does not explicitly know about or the ingestion of the event will fail.

Example:

```
Event: Purchase
Attributes: Total, OrderNum

// Ingestion: ALL
SDK.track("Purchase", mapOf("Total" to 1234, "OrderNum" to 4321)) // success
SDK.track("Purchase", mapOf("Total" to 1234)) // fail
SDK.track("Purchase", mapOf("Total" to 1234, "OrderNum" to 4321, "Shipping" to 22)) // fail
SDK.track("Purchase") // fail
SDK.track("Purchase", mapOf("Tax" to 11)) // fail


// Ingestion: SOME
SDK.track("Purchase", mapOf("Total" to 1234)) // success
SDK.track("Purchase", mapOf("Total" to 1234, "OrderNum" to 4321)) // success
SDK.track("Purchase") // fail
SDK.track("Purchase", mapOf("Tax" to 11)) //fail
SDK.track("Purchase", mapOf("Total" to 1234, "Tax" to 11)) //fail

// Ingestion: NONE
SDK.track("Purchase") // this is the only way this will succeed
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I configured the events in journey builder (Mobile App Events) and it didn't give me the option to choose between All, Some, and None. Where do you choose that ?

Comment: That's part of the Journey definition.

Comment: It's technically "all, any, or none", but I've coined it all, some, or none for so long now it's hard to kick :)

Comment: (Updated comment) For future readers, All/Some/None refers to the "Filter" step in the Mobile App Event journey entry UI setup. We needed to choose "All criteria is met" in the filter in order to receive attributes from a mobile app event. This was not intuitive because attributes in our case were are all dynamic for each user that triggers the event, so we had the Filter set to "None" initially.

Comment: "None" is a completely acceptable use-case as is "any". Your comment could be misleading as setting it to "all" means that they _must send all configured attributes_ and that may not be what they want/need. That resolved your issue, but others will have sent "some" with none configured, or some with "all" configured, or anything with "none" configured: all of which will fail.